# mod rewrite Force HTTPS + WWW

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the following to force `www.` however I want to also force `https`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How would I edit that correctly to force `https` **AS WELL** as `www.`

Fixed main site with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Other domains on are now forced to include `https` I only want my main site to do it...

A different fix for main site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.DOMAIN.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Seems to work correctly. I moved my other domain to a different server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rule that you can use to force `www` and `https` in same rule:

```
# https and www in one rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Ordering of `RewriteCond` is very important here otherwise `%1` will not be captured correctly. First 2 conditions are or `OR`ed together and 3rd condition is `AND`ed.